# Create e virtual layer (points to line) refering to specific rows in attribute table

Tags: qgis, sql, virtual-layer, points-to-line

I have a point layer "Points" with the following attributes:

| Name | FromNode | ToNode | Startheight | Gradient | Length | Endheight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14870040 | 14870040 | 14870055 | 39 | 0.005 | 57.51 |  |
| 14870056 | 14870056 | 18880033 | 0 | 0.005 |  |  |
| 14870055 | 14870055 | 14870056 | 40 | 0.005 | 57.92 |  |
| 14870057 | 14870057 | 14870040 | 0 | 0.005 | 65.35 |  |
| 14870297 | 14870297 | 14870057 | 41 | 0.005 | 93.27 |  |

With the attributes I am able to generate a virtual layer as Polyline according to the "FromNode"/"ToNode" values:

```
select a.Name, a.FromNode, a.ToNode, a.Startheight, a.Gradient, a.Length, ''AS Endheight, makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
from Points a, Points b
where b.Name = a.ToNode
```

So line segments are generated where the start point of a segment is the same like the end point of the previous segment.

I'd like now to calculate the "Endheight" of the following segments based on the "Startheight" of the previous/first line segments (if "Startheight" is '0', else take "Startheight" here '41') and based on the other fields "Gradient", "Length".
The formula should look like: "Endheight" = "Startheight" - ("Gradient" * "Length").

The problem for me is to refer to the right row where "FromNode" = "ToNode".

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple field to order the segments, so to know the "before" or "after" segment, one must recursively build the chain.

Also, let's note that a segment end height is the same as the next segment start height.

Create a layer/virtual layer of your segments, call is "segments"

Create a new virtual layer to recursively compute the missing fields

```sql
with RECURSIVE rec(geometry,Name,FromNode,ToNode,Startheight,Gradient,Length,Endheight) AS (
    select a.geometry, a.Name, a.FromNode, a.ToNode, a.Startheight, a.Gradient, a.Length, 
          a.Startheight - (a.Gradient * a.Length) AS Endheight -- compute 1st segment end height
    from segments a
    where a.Startheight > 0 --start the computation where a start height is defined
UNION ALL
    select b.geometry, b.Name, b.FromNode, b.ToNode, 
           a.Endheight as Startheight, --Previous end is current start
           b.Gradient, b.Length, 
           a.Endheight - (b.Gradient * b.Length) AS Endheight --current start height is not defined yet, use previous end height
    from  rec a,  segments b
    where b.Name = a.ToNode
          and b.Startheight = 0 --stop the recursion when a segment in the path has a start height
)
SELECT * FROM rec;
```

If you want to skip creating the segments layer first, you can embed it in its own CTE:

```sql
with RECURSIVE 
segments AS (
  select a.Name, a.FromNode, a.ToNode, a.Startheight, a.Gradient, a.Length, ''AS Endheight, makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
  from Points a, Points b
  where b.Name = a.ToNode),
rec(geometry,Name,FromNode,ToNode,Startheight,Gradient,Length,Endheight) AS ( ...
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help @JGH! The code is working - great. I tried to add the "makeline"-comment to generate the linesegments directly from the points layer, but I was not able to get a proper result. Where do I need to put the "makeline" in the code?

Comment: What if I have more than 1 defined "Startheight" in the points layer? Some backgrounds for the code: I need to plan a pipenetwork. The points are the nodes, the linesegments should be the links. Some of the nodes (points) have a defined height ("Startheight") the others not. So the "Endheight" is calculated based on the given values "Gradient", "Length" (dynamic according to the location of the connecting nodes) and the "Start/Endheight" (which is partly given, and dynamic). I tested the code with more than 1 defined "Startheight". The results have more linesegments than they should have.

Comment: Maybe it is better to add a Field "Fixheight" with the known values? So the calculation of "Start/Endheight" can refer to "Fixheight"?

Comment: 1)create another virtual layer with your code to create the segments 2) if you have multiple points with a start height in a path, then stop the recursion when it finds one: change  `... where b.Name = a.ToNode` to `... where b.Name = a.ToNode and b.Startheight = 0` 3)?

Comment: 1) I'd like to create the resulting layer directly from the input layer (points), without a need to create a segments layer.

Comment: 2) Jep, got it working - thanks!

Comment: 3) It's better to use an extra column "Fixheights" so that "Startheight" can be calculated. 
 With this I can check and compare the calculations afterwords.

Comment: see edit for building the segments in a CTE